# Fade UITableView section index in and out when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm currently working on a project on ios in swift with a table view that includes an section index.
I want to hide the section index when i'm on the top of the table view and then show it when i begin to scroll down.Typically what does the Music App.

I've searched for section index property in UITableView but I didn't find anything for hiding it.

Can anyone help me ?

I implement the section index in this function :

```
    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

        return everySections

    }
```

Here is everySections declaration :

```
    var everySections : [String] {
        get {
            let tempArray = Array(artistsSectioned.keys) as [String]
            let tempEverySections = tempArray.sort(<)

            return tempEverySections
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us the code of how you added section index!!

Comment: Maybe you can set the index view height to 0 when your scroll y position is null

Comment: I've never done this, but maybe you could use an extra UIView that you stick on top of the UITableView when scrolling begins or a specific indexPath has been reached.. ?

Comment: Maybe i am not clear, what i want to hide is the vertical bar on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the section index color and background color to fade the section index in and out:

Set the tableView delegate to self and implement this `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var alpha: CGFloat = 1
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 1 {
        alpha = 0
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 20 {
        alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / CGFloat(20)
    }
    tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: alpha)
    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: alpha)
}
```

This fades the section index in and out during the first 20 pt of scrolling. Just change the 20 any value you like if you want to fade it slower or faster.

To initially hide the section index set both colors to clearColor in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.clearColor()
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Do you know any way to get the showing/hiding animated ?